# Retrieve Data from realtime database on android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm trying to read data from my database but it looks i'm failed, please help me

Here's my code
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as image.

Comment: Also you're not getting everything in your `Firend` object because you're crossing one more unique id between your data and the node, you're referencing at.

Answer (score 0):

there exist a child node in "friendlist" which is a random string and you are trying to get data from friendlist node which will off course be null

and more over even if the data is not null always try to bound the code in a try catch or check if the value is not null. it will not let the app crash at run time.

and for furture refernce have a look at the docs => https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write